# Value error while using roboflow object detection Yolov4 pytorch model on custom dataset

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, yolov4, roboflow, dataset

We are using Roboflow for object detection using Yolov4 Pytorch model for our custom data set. During the training process, we are getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pytorch-YOLOv4/train.py", line 447, in <module>
    device=device, )
  File "./pytorch-YOLOv4/train.py", line 310, in train
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 856, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 881, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 394, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 7.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/pytorch-YOLOv4/dataset.py", line 382, in __getitem__
    out_bboxes1[:min(out_bboxes.shape[0], self.cfg.boxes)] = out_bboxes[:min(out_bboxes.shape[0], self.cfg.boxes)]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/pytorch-YOLOv4/dataset.py", line 385, in __getitem__
    out_bboxes1[:min(out_bboxes.shape[0], self.cfg.boxes)] = out_bboxes[:min(out_bboxes.shape[0], self.cfg.boxes)]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (0,5)
```

Comment: So... what have you tried to fix it so far? Seems like you should convert some lists to numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the info of your params, but the log said something wrong with your code:

```py
out_bboxes1[:min(out_bboxes.shape[0], self.cfg.boxes)] \
    = out_bboxes[:min(out_bboxes.shape[0], self.cfg.boxes)]
```

The first error said your param `out_bboxes` has no attribute 'shape', because it's a `list` object. So you can consider change it's datatype as you need.